# responsive image in swing

Tags: java, image, swing

Just wondering if anyone knows how to make an image in a java application using swing adjust based on your screen size, at the moment when i maximize my application the image stays at the same size, it does not re-adjust, any ideas?

```
JLabel logo = new JLabel();
ImageIcon imgLogo = new ImageIcon("path-to-image/logo.png");
logo.setIcon(imgLogo);
add(logo);
```

This is the code i have so far, it is positioned at the top of my application, i only want it to adjust horizontally when i re-size the window.

Like in web design you can usually just set the image to a percentage value, but i am unsure about how it is done in Swing or if it is even possible.

Comment: Resizable images are typically achieved using Java-2D in an `Override` of the `paint(Graphics)` (AWT) or `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  I am unsure whether to mark this for closure based on 'must have minimal understanding of the problem' but will wait to see how you react to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to redraw the PNG file each time the width changes.

add a `ComponentListener` to the `JFrame`, and override the `componentResized` method. Then you will have to use the `Image.getScaledInstance` method to resize the image depending upon the size of the `JFrame`

Comment: See [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html).

Comment: and delayed by Swing Timer after resize ended

Comment: The article seems pretty old @AndrewThompson is it still relevant today?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: This answer is probably bad advice.. In a Swing component, just override paintComponent and use drawImage to scale on the fly. It's faster and easier (IMO).